# Compiler error using struct and typedef

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have the following files in my VS project:

```
// list.h

#include "node.h"

typedef struct list list_t;

void push_back(list_t* list_ptr, void* item);
```

```
// node.h

typedef struct node node_t;
```

```
// node.c

#include "node.h"

struct node
{
   node_t* next;
};
```

```
// list.c

#include "list.h"


struct list
{
    node_t* head;
};

void push_back(list_t* list_ptr, void* item)
{
   if(!list_ptr)
       return;

   node_t* node_ptr; // Here I have two compiler errors
}
```

I have the compiler errors: [Compiler Error C2275](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76c9k4ah%28v=vs.110%29) and [Compiler Error C2065](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewcf0002%28v=vs.110%29).

Why? How can i fix this problem?

Comment: I get a compiler error at `list_t`. That type has not been defined.

Comment: Have you `#included` the header files in list.c?

Comment: @larsmans don't worry about list_t, it is not the problem. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @Nick: Ok.  Is the above now your **exact** code?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The exact code is too long, but there are all include, typedef and struct.

Comment: @Nick: Put it another way; if you create a new project with just the above code, do you get the exact same error message?  This is very important; if you're asking questions about compiler error messages/syntax errors, you need to be precise about what code you're using, otherwise people will be left guessing.

Comment: What @OliCharlesworth hints at is that its pretty hard to answer this kind of question without an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you're right I'll create a new project and i'll let you know if there are differences

Comment: @Nick - The trick is to try to reproduce the problem with the *minimum* possible code.

Comment: I found the _stupid_ error, I edited the question so it is clear now.

Comment: Side note: try to avoid using the suffix `_t`. Besides the fact that it is useless, it is also [reserved by POSIX](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html). You can safely write `typedef struct node node` and use `node` instead of introducing `node_t`.

Comment: Compiles without errors here, just warnings about unused parameter and variable. There must be more in `push_back` to cause the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what list.h looks like after the pre-processor handles the `#include` lines (some comments excluded):

```
// list.h 

typedef struct node node_t;

typedef struct list list_t; 

void push_back(list_t* list_ptr, void* item);
```

When you use this header inside list.c, the compiler has problems with `struct node` because it is not defined in this context.  It is only defined in node.c, but the compiler can't see that definition from list.c.

Since you're only using pointers to `node_t`, try changing node.h to look like this:

```
// node.h     

struct node;
typedef struct node node_t;
```

Now, you've pre-declared that there is a data type called `struct node`.  It's enough information for the compiler to handle `typedef`s and create pointers, but since it hasn't been completely defined you can't declare an object of type `struct node` or de-reference a `struct node` pointer.